How to change the style of `footnote` with `\circled`?
I have a wheel \circled to create circle outside the arabic number as below, now I want to change the style of \thefootnote, but the mwe below maybe confrant with some expandable issues, how to promote it?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 1.3em] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\circled{footnote}}
\begin{document}
    I can eat the class with\footnote{footnote footnote} glass.I can eat the class with\footnote{footnote footnote} glass.I can eat the class with\footnote{footnote footnote} glass.I can eat the class with\footnote{footnote footnote} glass.I can eat the class with\footnote{footnote footnote} glass.
\end{document}

All in all, I also wonder what are the properties of a counter, what could we do with a counter except \arabic, \alph, \value?

Thanks to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I redfine the macro \@thefnmark and it works. I have appended my solution to the origin question.

please don't put answers into questions. if you have an answer to add, write a new answer to the duplicate question.

@Explorer I rolled back your edit. You don't need to add an answer to your question. Future users with the same problem will be able to find Ulrike's solution in the linked duplicate. That's why there is a link at the top of your question.

Okay, I know, thanks to your kindness and patience. Actually I didn't search the link on tse with keyword footnoteor number style like, however it needs the keyword tikzpicture(；′⌒`)
